# Aplicação de uso intenso de CPU bloqueia requisições concorrentes

Tags: node.js

Numa aplicação web é comum que para cada requisição seja criado uma nova thread que lida com todo processamento e se por algum motivo a thread ficar bloqueada por execuar uma tarefa pesada, o recurso fica alocado para a requisição.

Entendo que isso é ineficiente pois os recursos alocados são mal utilizados e causa um consumo excessivo de recursos do servidor.

Entretanto ao estudar Node, testei o seguinte código que calcula um número primo e por consequência faz uma utilização intensa de CPU;

**calc-primo.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var isPrime = require('./number-util').isPrime;

var count = 1;
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('Requisição #' + count++);
    console.time('Tempo');

    var number = 0;
    var numberOfPrimes = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(isPrime(++number)) numberOfPrimes++;
        if(numberOfPrimes === 1000000) break;
    }
    res.end("Número: " + number);
    console.timeEnd('Tempo');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Executei o comando `node calc-primo.js` e no navegador abrir 2 tabs e em cada uma fiz uma requisição ao `localhost:3000`. Na consola obtive o seguinte resultado:

> Requisição #1
>   Tempo: 12458ms
>   Requisição #2
>   Tempo: 12358ms

Devido a natureza do Node, a requisição `#2` só recebeu uma resposta depois da requisição `#1`, mas a segunda requisição esperou cerca de 12 segundos até ser processada e mais 12 para obter uma resposta.

Apesar de otimizar os recursos do servidor, há uma maior lentidão para obter uma resposta. Vi que isso pode ser resolvido utilizando o módulo `cluster` e ter multiplas instâncias do event loop.

**1) Ao adicionar multiplas instâncias do event loop (sendo que cada instância é uma nova thread), não viola o princípio do Node que é otimizar os recursos do servidor?**

**2) O fato do Node ter uma única thread principal não deixa o sistema mais lento para requisições que  necessitam de processamentos mais pesados, uma vez que haverá concorrência?**

Answer (score 0):

**Respondendo a pergunta 1:** O Node.js usa uma abordagem que procura otimizar os recursos de hardware (processador e memoria) pois descarta o uso de threads em estado sleep, ou seja, você não tem threads ociosas esperando por algum evento de I/O responder. Contudo se por acaso o servidor possuir mais de um processador você teria um event loop processando em apenas um processador e deixaria os outros ociosos, nesse caso o "cluster" é uma boa opção. Imagine que você possui 3 processadores e configura o cluster do node com 3, nesse caso existiriam 3 event loops para atender as suas requisições.

**Respondendo a pergunta 2:** Sim, o node não é uma boa abordagem para sistemas que demandam alto uso da cpu no banck-end, pois como o event-loop e single thread ele vai engarrafar as requisições. Ele é ideal para sistemas que delegam o trabalho para algum outro dispositivo que não seja o processador, como por exemplo a memoria (primaria ou secundaria), banco de dados ou a placa de rede.